# Print a template variable on an overwritten admin form in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I have a Doctor-model which has a field called first_created. It is just a DateField that is auto_add_now, hence it is not displayed when editing a doctor in the admin interface.

I want to display this field on the admin interface, at the top of the site as say, a static  or something. It is supposed to ease the process of typing in data in other fields, so a sentence like "three months from now" will make more sense.

Since the model should according to the documentation, should hold all model fields as template variables, I am trying to overwrite the change_form.html and outputting {{ doctor.first_created }}. But it is not working.

I've tried multiple things, even things like looping over opts.fields and printing out methods on these fields like value_to_string. Not working.

How can I print first_created as a template variable in change_form.html?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what `doctor` is in the context of the edit page. Is it the object being edited? That's passed to the template as `original`, so you should be able to do `{{ original.first_created }}`.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Had not seen this anywhere in the documentation. Thanks alot.

Comment: No, it's not in the documentation - but the advantage of open source is that you can read the code.